# Masonry column shift tweaks

Tags: jquery, css

Hi guys can you help me edit the code here. I want the effect to be clickable and not the hover effect.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html

This is the current code:

```
$container.find('.shifty-item').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css({ height: "+=100" });
    // note that element is passed in, not jQuery object
    $container.isotope( 'shiftColumnOfItem', this );
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css({ height: "-=100" });
    $container.isotope( 'shiftColumnOfItem', this );
  }
);
```

I tried to use bind.('click', function) but it's not working. Also tried adding a CSS class but that doesn't solve the problem ethier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the code and from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) hover has two functions/handlers.

`$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)`

In order to change this to click, which only has one, you need to "simulate" the two states in hover.

```
$container.find('.shifty-item').click(function({
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
        $(this).css({ height: "-=100" });
        $container.isotope( 'shiftColumnOfItem', this );
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css({ height: "+=100" });
        $container.isotope( 'shiftColumnOfItem', this );
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

This code can be further optimized but you get the point.

Comment: Hi tried your code, i've also added my previous code that has toggleClass. Now it works. Thank you

Comment: I have 1 more problem, I've changed 'css' to 'animate'. Though it's not working properly. I've tried adding 


  `-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in 0.2s`
    `-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in 0.2s`
    `-o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in 0.2s`
    `-ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in 0.2s`
    `transition: all 0.6s ease-in 0.2s`

But still no luck

Comment: i am not what the problem might be. try opening a new q if you can't find something in old questions